# Php Validation Error is there

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$username=$_POST['username'];
$error="";

if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $error="Please enter a valid email";
}   
if($email!==null && $email!=="" && $password!==null && $password!=="" && $username!==null && $username!=="")
{
    $error="Please enter all the fields first";
}   


}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>User Login System</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Register-form">
        <h1>Registration form</h1>
        <form id="register-form" method="post" action="" >
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <label>UserName</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
            <span><?php echo $error;?></span>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After running this code this error is coming in the validation error variable i have initalized error variable but it is saying undefined error variable

> Notice: Undefined variable: error in C:\xampp\htdocs\UserLogin\index.php on line 39

This is the error which is showing up can you please tell me the solution of this problem.Thanks in advance.

Basically the problem is with $error variable which is there in the script please tell me if i remove it or can i modify so that my problem is solved.

Comment: use a ternary operator or `isset()` for it, that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: Move the initialization outside the conditional.

Comment: it is not working

Comment: declare `$error="";` variable above/before `if(isset($_POST['submit']))...` . If $_POST['submit'] is not set $error is not available